# How do I develop a large whitelist of pages for a PHP include?

Tags: php

It's clear that for any reasonable-sized website, building it in modules using PHP includes has great advantages, so I chose to dynamically create the page content using includes. I was against the idea of including the header and footer, so I did the inverse like this (index.php):

```
    if(isset($_GET['page']))
    {
        $whitelist = array("contact","about","access", etc.);
        if(in_array($_GET['page'], $whitelist))
        {
           include($_GET['page'].".php");
        }

    }
    else
    {
        include('home.php');
    }
```

Some people object to this on security grounds (although they never give an alternative), but I find it to be a neat solution. My question is, what happens when my site has hundreds or even thousands of pages? Do I just keep adding variables to the whitelist array until it becomes huge, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your site has hundreds or thousands of pages, all unique, you'll probably be storing them in database. And their URL slugs too (`contact`, `about`, etc.). So if get value is a valid slug (exists in table), here you go.

Comment: Thank you, make sense as a database is designed to search through lots of data.

Answer (score 0):

use a database to whitelist pages. That way you can get config settings and permissions in one go.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience,  whitelisting page to include them in php is not a good practice. because adding new page or modifying old pages name requires changing this list. I think it's better to use another form of address validation. **Using classes** like MVC or **validating the address based on a pattern** or maybe using rewrite of apache are good practices. Anyway, it's up to you!